# Can code for applications that run exclusively on Azure Government be written off shore by non citizens?

Tags: azure

What restrictions, if any, exist on writing code for applications that run exclusively on Azure Government?

For example, can applications running on AG be written off shore by non USA citizens?

After reading the AG documentation I do not see any restrictions, yet the development community I work with thinks that there are a number of restrictions.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not related to actual code

Answer (score 0):

With US Government and Microsoft standards this should not be done. The correct way is to use a public Azure instances, have the non-US Citizens have access to. That is the one where they can access to and code on. Then the code can move to Azure per the GOV ORG standards. Each ORG like DoD has different standards that must be followed.

Comment: Can you offer a reference to the specific Microsoft standards?  After reading all of the documents from the Microsoft Azure Gov. web site I cannot find any documents that speak to what restrictions a company should place on development.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/subscription-agreement/government/

Comment: TY - this was exactly what I was looking for and was unable to find!

Comment: Are you currently using Azure GOV? There is some nice things in Azure that work great in Azure GOV, But there are things that do not work at all in Azure Gov.